# Codeigniter redirect()->to() doesnt work in __construct()

Tags: codeigniter-4

I have code in my controller

```
public function __construct()
{
   return redirect()->to('/auth');
   $this->validation =
     \Config\Services::validation();
   $this->title = 'Header Menu';
   $this->controller = 'user';
}

public function index()
{
  $data = [
     'title_prefix' => 'Profil',
     'title' => $this->title,
     'controller' => $this->controller,
     'button_add' => false,
     'validation' => $this->validation
    ];

  return view('user/index', $data);
}
```

it still show view('user/index'). How to get to return redirect()->to('/auth') in __construct() ?
sorry i'm not speaking english well

Answer (score 3):

It is an expected behavior that `redirect()` doesn't work inside a constructor.

`redirect()` in CI4 doesn't just set headers but return a RedirectResponse object.
Problem is : while being in the constructor of your controller, you can't return an instance of something else. **You're trying to construct a Controller not a RedirectResponse.**

Good practice is to use [Controller Filters](https://codeigniter4.github.io/CodeIgniter4/incoming/filters.html)

Or you could add the `redirect()` inside your index function if there's only at this endpoint that you would like to redirect the user.

Here's an example of the filter that would fit your need  :
**Watch out your CI version. The parameter `$arguments` is needed since 4.0.4. Otherwise you have to remove it**

```
<?php

namespace App\Filters;

use CodeIgniter\HTTP\RequestInterface;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\ResponseInterface;
use CodeIgniter\Filters\FilterInterface;

class AuthFilter implements FilterInterface {

    public function before(RequestInterface $request, $arguments = null) {
        return redirect()->to('/auth');
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------

    public function after(RequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, $arguments = null) {
    }

}
```

And in your `app/Config/Filters` edit those 2 variables in order to activate your filter :

```
public $aliases = [
        'auth' => \CodeIgniter\Filters\AuthFilter::class,
    ];
public $globals = [
        'before' => ['auth' => 'the_routes_you_want_to_redirect']
    ];
```

You might want to check this thread aswell : https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-74537.html

Answer (score 1):

you can't use `redirect()` inside `__construct()` function or `initController()` directly.
But you can use `$response` parameter in `initController()` or `$this->response` attribute.

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/65814413/1462903

in controller class

```
<?php namespace App\Controllers;

class Data extends BaseController
{
    public function initController(\CodeIgniter\HTTP\RequestInterface $request, \CodeIgniter\HTTP\ResponseInterface $response, \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        // Do Not Edit This Line
        parent::initController($request, $response, $logger);
        
        if($this->session->get('is_loggedin') !== true){
            $response->redirect(base_url('login')); // or use $this->response->redirect(base_url('login'));
        } 
        
    }
    
    public function index()
    {
        return view('dashboard');
    }
}
```

in **BaseController** class

```
/**
 * Constructor.
 */
public function initController(\CodeIgniter\HTTP\RequestInterface $request, \CodeIgniter\HTTP\ResponseInterface $response, \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger)
{
    // Do Not Edit This Line
    parent::initController($request, $response, $logger);

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Preload any models, libraries, etc, here.
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------

    $this->session = \Config\Services::session();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 header("Location: ".site_url().'/dashboard');
 die();
```