# CodeIgniter4 - pre-condition for all methods from controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I'm using CodeIgniter 4.

I have 2 controllers:

```
<?php namespace App\Controllers;

class Dashboard extends BaseController{

    public function index(){
        
        //pre-condition - logged
        if(!$this->session->has("email")){

            //go to login
            return redirect()->route("login");

        }

        return view("dashboard");

    }

}

//---------------------

class Profile extends BaseController{...}
```

In those 2 controllers I have some methods which represent routes `/dashboard`, `/profile`, `/profile/settings`, etc.

In every method I have the same pre-codition `if(...){ return redirect()->route("login"); }`.

This pre-condition check if user is logged.

How I can set this pre-condition to be at all methods from controller, without rewriting in every method from `Dashboard` and `Profile`?

Comment: why not you put your condition on Construct function?

Comment: @MD.JubairMizan I don't know how. I'm relative new with CodeIgniter and PHP.

Comment: I am writting a answer try this after call your class  it should work

Comment: A better practice is to use Controller Filters. You should take a look at this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63048335/codeigniter-redirect-to-doesnt-work-in-construct/63049135#63049135 and the doc : https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/incoming/filters.html.
They answer, by design, your question

Comment: @ViLar Really thank you. It is better/elegant than what I have done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    if ( ! $this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
    { 
        redirect('login');
    }
}
```

Comment: I get error: `Cannot call constructor` at `parent::__construct();` and in PhpStorm I have this warning `Potentially polymorphic call. The code may be inoperable depending on the actual class instance passed as the argument.`

Comment: try to remove parent::__construct(); and Put this before your class "use CodeIgniter\Controller;"

Comment: I updated my question. I added the code of class `Dashboard`. Can you show me using the code I added?

Comment: did you follow my previous comment structure it should work with this

Comment: I removed `parent::__construct();`, but I'm stuck at `Put this before your class "use CodeIgniter\Controller;"`. I'm not sure I know where do you mean.

Comment: use CodeIgniter\Controller; put this after <?php namespace App\Controllers; this line of code

Comment: I no longer get error, but the redirect not works. And the if-statement is true.

Comment: as per CI 4 Use this  "return redirect()->to('login');"

Comment: can you use echo "test" before redirect() this is for check you are under the condition

Comment: Yes, I have `echo` right before `redirect` and inside of the `if`. And it is printed on page, but no redirect.

Comment: did you use route if you are using route then try it return redirect()->route('named_route');

Comment: Try previous one if you are using route otherwise try this " return redirect()->to(base_url('public/login')); "

Comment: Nothing works. I just read that in CI4 can't redirect from `construct`

Comment: header('Location: '.base_url().'login'); exit();  Try this instead of redirect()

Answer (score -1):

You can run code in every method of a Controller by running it in the `__construct()` method:-

```
class Auth_Controller extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct()
    {
         parent::__construct();
    if ( ! $this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
    { 
        redirect('login');
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: PhpStorm: `Undefined class 'CI_Controller' `.

Comment: This is a CI3 answer. Question here is under CI4