# Wont redirect on __constrruct function - Codeigniter 4

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4

so i have this function on my controllers to check if the user is logged in or not, but it wont redirect to the login page when user is not logged in

```
public function __construct()
    {
        if(session()->get('logged_in') !== true)
        {
            redirect('login');
        }
    }
```

anyone has a solution for this? or should i put the session check on every function?
like

```
public function examplefunction()
{
   if(session()->get('logged_in') !== true)
   {
      redirect('login');
   }
   //run other codes
}
```

Comment: Could you please check this - https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/incoming/filters.html

Comment: If you need to use a constructor in your class make sure you extend the parent constructor: example here: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/extending/core_classes.html#extending-core-classes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Codeigniter redirect()->to() doesnt work in \_\_construct()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63048335/codeigniter-redirect-to-doesnt-work-in-construct)

Answer (score 5):

in codeigniter 4 there is a class name filter u can create class for authentication, u can read the documentation for more details.

this is the solution for your problem

1. create file **Auth.php** inside **App/Filters** folder

```
<?php

namespace App\Filters;

use CodeIgniter\HTTP\RequestInterface;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\ResponseInterface;
use CodeIgniter\Filters\FilterInterface;

class Auth implements FilterInterface
{
    public function before(RequestInterface $request)
    {
        if(session()->get('logged_in') !== true)
        {
           return redirect()->to('login');
        }
    }


    //--------------------------------------------------------------------

    public function after(RequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response)
    {
        // Do something here
    }
}
```

2. add your your new filter inside filters **App/Config/Filters.php** class to make it work

```
public $aliases = [
        'csrf'          => \CodeIgniter\Filters\CSRF::class,
        'toolbar'       => \CodeIgniter\Filters\DebugToolbar::class,
        'honeypot'      => \CodeIgniter\Filters\Honeypot::class,
        'auth'          => \App\Filters\Auth::class,
    ];
```

3. in your **Routes.php** u can use that filter to spesify what route use run that filter before go to the route you want.

for single route

```
$routes->get('examplefunction', 'ControllerName::examplefunction', ['filter' => 'auth']);
```

for route group

```
$routes->group('', ['filter' => 'auth'], function ($routes) {
    $routes->get('/', 'ControllerName::examplefunction');
    $routes->get('examplefunction2', 'ControllerName::examplefunction2');
};
```

so that filter will executed before all single route inside the group run.

i hope this help you

Comment: This is totally the correct answer. For login checks and redirection in case prevent access without login you should really use filters. Also in your controllers you shouldn't really use the __construct magic method but the __init one that already exists in your BaseController.